# ¿Como puedo escribir el resultado de dos sumas con input sin usar alert o document.write? y gracias

Tags: javascript, html5

quiero que el resultado aparesca escrito al lado del boton como un < p > para despues decorar todo con css pero nose como hacerlo para que aparesca escrito sin que se resetee toda la pagina (documen.write) o que no aparesca un cuadro de dialogo (alert)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" name="nota1">
        <input type="text" name="nota2">
    <button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>

<script>
  function sub(){
  nota1 = document.getElementsByName("nota1")[0].value;
  nota2 = document.getElementsByName("nota2")[0].value;

  var total= Number(nota1) + Number(nota2);
    alert (total);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes añadir un elemento dic con un nombre o id, luego lo recibes como haces con los input, y detrás el valor de html de ese div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un label puede ser.

```js
function sub(){
  nota1 = document.getElementsByName("nota1")[0].value;
  nota2 = document.getElementsByName("nota2")[0].value;

  var total= Number(nota1) + Number(nota2);
    
    document.querySelector("#suma").textContent = total
    
    }
```

```html
<html>
<input type="text" name="nota1">
        <input type="text" name="nota2">
    <button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>
    <label id="suma"></label>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: @JuanDavidAza recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te respondió tu pregunta. Haz clic en el tick a la izquierda de la respuesta, bajo los votos